# How do show excel is working with the busy (hourglass) mouse cursor when running a python script in xlwings?

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I've written a script in python for MS Excel which pulls data from a MySQL database, processes it into a format I want and then writes the data to Excel. I'm using xlwings to achieve this.

The process takes about 7 seconds and during that time the Excel user doesn't know that a process is happening.

How can I show the busy cursor from xlwings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, xkwings does not yet support this: an issue to do so was created in  Oct 27, 2016 but is not yet resolved:

- http://github.com/xlwings/xlwings/issues/578

Comment: Thanks for the answer, a workaround is to use the VBA function so my VBA has Application.Cursor = xlWait before RunPython ("import xl_code; xl_code.xl_start()") and then Application.Cursor = xlDefault

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Patrick Artner for pointing out this feature is sadly not implemented.

However I found a workaround by changing the cursor before and after the Runpython command in VBA like this:

```
Application.Cursor = xlWait
RunPython ("import xl_code; xl_code.xl_start()")
Application.Cursor = xlDefault
```